# prolog issue output every 2 elements

Tags: prolog

Write a Prolog predicate `everynth(N, X)`, that outputs every `N`<sup>th</sup> element of the list `X`.

```
?- everynth(1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).
1 2 3 4 5 6
true.
?- everynth(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).
2 4 6
true.
```

Here is what I tried, though I don't know to use recursion properly:

```
everynth(1, [X|_]) :-
    write(X),
    write(' ').
everynth(N, [_|H]) :-
    M is N - 1,
    everynth(M, H).
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as "homework" and tell us what you have tried so far and what your problem is at the moment. We won't just give you a solution here. If it isn't, please describe what you are actually trying to achieve, and we can figure out the best way.

Comment: @user1400451 why do it with a loop and not with recursion?

Comment: i think i can cut it down every time, recursion should be another way, but i dont really know recursion, because i just start study this.

Comment: I replaced a `,` with a `.` in your code, it wasn't correct Prolog syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:- use_module(library(dialect/hprolog)).


everynth(N,X) :- nth1(N,X,Elem),
                 write(Elem),
                 write(' '),
                 split_at(N,X,_,NewX),
                 everynthHelper(N,NewX).

everynthHelper(N,X) :- length(X,LengthX),
                       N > LengthX, !. 
everynthHelper(N,X) :- nth1(N,X,Elem),
                       write(Elem),
                       write(' '),
                       split_at(N,X,_,NewX),
                       everynthHelper(N,NewX).
```

I implemented a separate helper because the first successful call to everynthHelper/2 ensures that we will output `true` at the end.

Comment: thanks guys, thanks for your help. really appreciate for that

Comment: please approve the answer so anyone can use it later.

Comment: i tried it out but program say undefined procedure split_at. what is split_at use for?

Comment: can you help fix it? i will submit this home work today. program say undefined procedure split_at. what is that? i cant run it

Comment: it was running well for me, I'll try in a minute and give feedback here.

Comment: I have forgotten ':-' for use_module/1 at the first line, now I corrected and it runs OK.